# How to host a private static web site in Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I want to host a **static** web app containing HTML/CSS/JS only and some interlinking between HTML pages.

I am successfully able to access the app if I make the bucket **public** but I don't want to make the app public and I want that **only authenticated users** (People of the organization) can access that app.

When I make it private then CSS/JS stops working because the index.html can not access those files due to permission issue.

How to achieve this?

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible. The static website feature requires objects to be public. Any object requiring authorization will return a 403 error.

Answer (score 7):

As said by John, you can't achieve this with Cloud Storage. However you can use App Engine standard with IAP.

For this, get your sources and build a `app.yaml` file with this content

```
runtime: python3

handlers:
- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: /statics
  static_dir: statics

- url: /.*
  script: index.html
```

Then deploy it `gcloud app deploy`

Then, go to `identity aware proxy page` and activate IAP for your App Engine service.

Finally, you can select your App Engine service, go on the info panel on the right and click on add member. You can add a single user, a group or a company. (all needs to have a Google Account. Works well with Google Workspace company for example); and add the role IAP secured Web App user

[image]

Comment: This has been a great help! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by adding the `<base>` tag inside `<head>`:

`<base href="https://storage.cloud.google.com/<bucket>/path/to/site/root/"/>`

Normal CSS and JS will work.
However calling `fetch` to load additional files might not work due to CORS.

Comment: That worked lol. html, css and js loads. woff (fonts) do not. Any idea how to handle it?